# Jetpack Compose: how to call a AndroidView component method on state change?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Compose component MyCompose wraps MyView. MyView has a method `foo` that I want to call when MyCompose's state change from false to true.
How do I achieve this?

```
class MyView: FrameLayout{
  fun foo(){...}
}



@Composable
fun MyCompose(...) {
    
    val state = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    
    // call view.foo() when state.value change from false to true
    
    AndroidView(
        modifier = modifier,
        factory = { ctx -> MyView(ctx) },
        update = { view ->
            // ....
        }

    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **`update`** attribute in the `AndroidView`

```
    var state by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    AndroidView(
        factory = { context ->

            MaterialButton(context).apply {
                text = "Initial Value"
            }
        },
        update = {
            it.text = text

            if (state){
                it.setBackgroundTintList(
                    ContextCompat.getColorStateList(
                        context,
                        R.color.black
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    )
```

Comment: if i have a state2 that changes, then will setBackgroundTintList be called multiple times?

Comment: @Mars put in the update block your logic. It is just an example.

Comment: this update is "on any state updates", so when any other non related state updates, like state2, while `state` remains unchanged in "true". it it triggers unwanted `setBackgroundTintList`. In my case, my method foo is really critical so it can only called on state's rising edge

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a better way to implement it, but I solved such a problem like this:

```
@Composable
fun MyCompose(...) {        
    val state = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var myView: MyView? = null
    AndroidView(
        modifier = modifier,
        factory = { ctx -> MyView(ctx)
                      .apply { myView = this }  
        },
        update = { view -> myView = view }   
    )

    if (state.value) {
        view?.foo()
    }
}
```

Comment: looks hacky, it is recommended?